# set::vector initialization with quotes in a numeric

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

So I came about a question about std::reduce which lead me to an example on. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce)

In this example I saw the following std::vector declaration:

```
    std::vector<double> v(10'000'007, 0.5);
```

What are these quotes doing here? I've never seen this before anywhere. Is this a new kind of C++ feature that I should know about?

Comment: That is C++'s digit separators. And it's been around since C++14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a new feature in C++14. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal):

> Optional single quotes(') may be inserted between the digits as a
>   separator. They are ignored by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a digit separator, as described in here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2209021

So, this code should be equivalent to

```
std::vector<double> v(10000007, 0.5);
```